# Should i set a column as NULL if there's records that will not use that specific column?

Tags: sql, database, dbnull

Does that make any difference?

Example:

I have a table with 5 columns, i use 3 columns for most things of my website, and 2 columns for the menu bar or anything else.

Comment: If there's no valid data to be put in those columns, then NULL seems the obvious way to go. What other options are you considering?

Comment: If you don't have something to store, then yes, it should be null. On the other hand, if columns will be mostly null, consider moving them to another table that you can cross reference when needed.

Comment: @RemyLebeau **if columns will be mostly null, consider moving them to another**. Would it make any difference if i dont move those records to another table? I use only one table for everything, and it's fine.

Comment: A single table for everything, with total of 5 columns. Sounds like your needs are not very complex right now and while that complexity remains true you are probably OK, but as complexity rises you will need to consider normalizing your  data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to see if the table contain logically grouped data. If it doesnt, try to normalise. Alternatively, setting the field to default value of null and deal with Null on the programming code.

Here is a good article on setting field to NULL:

https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/5222/why-shouldnt-we-allow-nulls